# How to Stack/Dump different SQL queries results into DataGridView?

Tags: c#, sql-server, datagridview

Any advice how can i stack/dump different SQL query results in DataGridView? If you think why I didn't create a hard table data holder for all results and dump into DataGridView. Yes that will works if you have in the same SQL server but those queries are from different server so need data holder for all my SQL queries result.

Sample:

[DNS1].[DB1].table1 results

[DNS2].[DB2].table2 results

[DNS3].[DB3].table3 results

Into DataGridView.

Hope you understand the scenario. Really appreciate your advice.

Comment: Could you combine your different SQL query results into one object before it's bound to the DataGridView?

You could use a Union in the database or a collection type within application/server domain.

Comment: That problem for those SQL server are not link. So i cannot union the results into one object.

Answer (score 0):

Retrieve your data from your databases into DataSets, then you can merge them into a big one (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataset.merge(v=vs.110).aspx), and use it as you DataGridView source.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I didn't know that dataset have merge. I am thinking dataset.append. Sorry I am just new in programming. I will look into this.